# Derivative of a Cross product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

There are four $3D$ vectors ($3\times 1$ matrix) $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c$  and $\vec u$ and a $3\times 3$ matrix $L$.

Considering the norm of the following cross product:
$$ f=\left\lVert ((\vec a-\vec u)-\vec b) \times ((\vec a- \vec u)-L\vec c)\right\rVert_2$$
how can I compute the partial derivatives of $f$ wrt $u$ and $L$, i.e.
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial L} $ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} $?
One approach I thought of was converting the first component of cross product to a skew symmetric matrix to turn the cross product to a matrix product. But it becomes very complicated to compute. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute a new variable $\{x=(u-a)\}$, multiply each side of the cross-product by $(-1)$, and square the function to obtain
$$\eqalign{
f^2
 &= \|(x+b)\times(x+Lc)\|_2^2 \cr
 &= \|(x\times Lc)+(b\times Lc)+(b\times x)\|_2^2 \cr
 &= \|XLc+BLc+Bx)\|_2^2 \cr
 &= (XLc+BLc+Bx):(XLc+BLc+Bx) \cr
 &= w:w \cr
}$$
where I've used $(B,X)$ to represent the skew-symmetric matrices corresponding to cross-products with respect to the vectors $(b,x)$, and a colon to represent the trace product, e.g. 
$$A:M={\rm tr}(A^TM)$$ 
Let's find the differential and gradient wrt $L$
$$\eqalign{
2f\,df &= 2w:dw \cr
 &= 2w:(X\,dL\,c+B\,dL\,c) \cr
 &= 2(X^T+B^T)wc^T:dL \cr
 &= 2(X^T+B^T)(XLc+BLc+Bx)c^T:dL \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}
 &= (X^T+B^T)(XLc+BLc+Bx)c^T\,f^{-1} \cr
 &= -(x+b)\times\Big((x\times Lc)+(b\times Lc)+(b\times x)\Big)c^T\,f^{-1} \cr
 &= \Bigg[\Big(a-u-b\Big)\times\Big(\big((u-a)\times Lc\big)+(b\times Lc)+\big(b\times(u-a)\big)\Big)\Bigg]c^T\,f^{-1} \cr
}$$
I'll leave $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ as an exercise for you; it's pretty much the same technique.

Here are a few hints 
$$\eqalign{
X &= U + A \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cr
}$$

**Update** (responding to your comment)
The third-order [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) $(E)$ is very useful for working with cross products.

Here are a few of its properties
$$\eqalign{
 B &= -E\cdot b \cr
Bx &= b\times x = E:bx^T = -b\cdot E\cdot x \cr
 b &= -\frac{1}{2}B:E \implies B:E = -2b \cr
}$$
Since any matrix can be decomposed into its symmetric and skew parts
$$\eqalign{
 M &= \frac{1}{2}(M+M^T) + \frac{1}{2}(M-M^T) \cr
   &= {\rm sym}(M) + {\rm skew}(M) \cr
   &=  Y + K \cr
}$$
and contracting with $E$ will annihilate the symmetric part 
$$\eqalign{M:E &= K:E \cr}$$
So now if we set 
$$M=wc^TL^T$$
we can write the result from your comment as
$$\eqalign{
f\,df &= M:dX + B^Tw:dx \cr
 &= -M:E\,dx + B^Tw:dx \cr
 &= (-K:E + B^Tw):dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= (2k + B^Tw)\,f^{-1} \cr
}$$
where $k$ is the vector associated with the skew matrix 
$K={\rm skew}(M)=-E\cdot k$.

I'll leave it to you to convert this expression back into terms of the original problem variables.

Comment: Thank you Greg for your answer, to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ according to $x=u-a$ and $dx=du$:
$$\eqalign{
2f\,df &= 2w:dw \cr
 &=2w:(dX\,L\,C+B\,dx) \cr
 &=wC^TL^T:dX+B^Tw:dx
}$$
But here could you please advise me how I can convert $dX$ to $dx$ ?